# OCaml- How to get tail of tuple list?

Tags: list, functional-programming, pattern-matching, tuples, ocaml

I'm a beginner to OCaml so I'm not sure if this is a right question. Anyway
let's say I had a list of tuples [(1,2);(3,4);(5,6);(7,8);(9,10)]. I am pattern matching in a function so

```
let rec func list = match list with 
    |(* base case here *)
    |head1::head2::tail -> func head1::tail;; (* error here *)
```

Not real code, just to illustrate what I'm going to explain. When I use that pattern matching the first time, head1 is (1,2), head2 is (3,4), but tail seems to be only (5,6) instead of (5,6)(7,8)(9,10)...if I'm right. After all I'm getting "Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b but an expression was expected of type ('a * 'b) list" so I assume that must be what's happening. In the pattern matching how can I make tail be all of (5,6)(7,8)(9,10)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true that `tail` is just `(5, 6)`. `tail` is the full tail of the list as you expected.

To fix the problem you're describing, I think you just need parentheses around `head1 :: tail`.

In OCaml, function application has high precedence. So this expression:

```
func head1 :: tail
```

is parsed as if it were parenthesized like this:

```
(func head1) :: tail
```

but what you want (I think) is:

```
func (head1 :: tail)
```

I suspect there are other problems in the code, but this might get you going.

Comment: ._________. you're right, that worked. Thanks!! Why does that make a difference though?

Comment: It's about operator precedence. I tried to explain above, let me know what's not clear.